# Como añadir un char a un array char

Tags: c++, array, string

```
char palabra[]="Hola Mundo";
char vocales[]="";
int i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(palabra);i++){
    if (palabra[i]=='a' ||palabra[i]=='e' ||palabra[i]=='i' ||palabra[i]=='o' ||palabra[i]=='u'){
        //aqui estaria la linea de codigo que necesito
    }
}
```

El resultado de `vocales`tendria que ser `"oauo"`

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser forzosamente un char? Porque ahí no es posible, como te comentan en la respuesta.
Si lo que quieres en realidad es extraer las vocales, hay otras formas más apropiadas para eso

A esto que acabas de hacer se le conoce como "Problema XY": quieres, en realidad, extraer las vocales, pero preguntas cómo añadir un char a un array char, cosa que no tiene nada que ver con el objetivo original tuyo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que tú estás llamando "*array char*" es una formación<sup>1</sup> de tamaño estático. Así pues `palabra` tiene una longitud estática de 11 caracteres (cuatro para `Hola`, cinco para `Mundo`, uno para el espacio  y otro para el carácter de finalización de cadena `\0`).

No puedes añadir ningún carácter (`char`) más.

---

Si realmente necesitas añadir caracteres, no podrás usar memoria estática, es decir, tendrás que usar memoria dinámica:

```
char *palabra = new char[11]{"Hola mundo"};
std::cout << palabra << '\n'; // Muestra "Hola mundo"

// Queremos añadir el carácter '!'
char *nueva_palabra = new char[12]{};
std::copy(palabra, palabra + 10, nueva_palabra); // Copiamos el texto original en una formación nueva
delete[] palabra;
nueva_palabra[11] = '!';  // Añadimos el carácter
nueva_palabra[12] = '\0'; // Marcamos el final de la cadena
std::cout << nueva_palabra << '\n'; // Muestra "Hola mundo!"
```

#### Propuesta.

Pero todo eso es un engorro, además de ser un estilo muy propenso a errores y nada acorde con las tendencias modernas, ya que has añadido la etiqueta [string](/questions/tagged/string) a la pregunta, usa `std::string`:

```
std::string palabra = "Hola mundo";
std::cout << palabra << '\n'; // Muestra "Hola mundo"

palabra.push_back('!'); // Añadimos el carácter
std::cout << palabra << '\n'; // Muestra "Hola mundo!"
```

Mucho más fácil y seguro.

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.